# Div gets messed up with I try to add text to it?

Tags: html, css

Basically, when I try to add a paragraph into one of the `<div>`'s I run into trouble. The page seems to be messed up. Is there anything wrong with my code? And, what are some things that my code needs to be improved?

Thanks!

```css
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style>
    * {
   font-family: georgia;
 }
 body {
    background-color: white;
 }
 #content {
   width: 60%;
   height: 1500px;
   margin: auto;
   
   
 }
 #header {
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px dashed;
   background-color: #44424D;

 }
 #left {
   width: 20%;
   height: 100%;
   display: inline-block;
  }
 #right {
   height: 100%;
   width: 20%;
      display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   left: 676px;
   
 }
 #name {
      font-family: big john;
      font-size: 50px;
   width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;   
   color: white;
 }
 .wot {
   background-color: #E6C88C;
 }
</style>
<head><title>Film Club</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
  <h1 id="name">The Film Club</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="left", class="wot">
        <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right", class="wot">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you define describe what you mean by *messed up*, please? Or can you provide a jsFiddle? Thanks!

Comment: messed up how? Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have commas in your HTML, which is incorrect.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="header">
        <h1 id="name">The Film Club</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="left" class="wot">
        <p>Test</p>
    </div>
    <div id="right" class="wot">
    </div>
</div>
```

Second, the heights of the divs with the text in is set to `100%` and the height of you `#content` div set to `1500px` so the divs expand to this full height. The height of a div is only applied when it contains content which is why it changes when you put text in. You can remove the height from the CSS, or set it to a more appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Two of your `<div>`s have commas separating the properties. Properties in html tags do not need to be separated by commas. They should just be separated by a space (this probably isn't even required, but you should do it in the interest of good style).

I'm going to assume the improper indentation is a result of posting the code, but if that's not the case, proper indentation is always a good way to improve your code.

Answer (score 0):

I have change the following CSS code css

```
#left {
      width: 20%;
      height: 100%;
      float:left;
      display: inline-block;
     }
#right {
      height: 100%;
      width: 20%;
      display: inline-block;
      position: relative;
      float: right;   
}
```

```css
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<style>
    * {
   font-family: georgia;
 }
 body {
    background-color: white;
 }
 #content {
   width: 60%;
   height: 1500px;
   margin: auto;
   
   
 }
 #header {
   height: 200px;
   border: 1px dashed;
   background-color: #44424D;

 }
 #left {
   width: 20%;
   height: 100%;
      float:left;
   display: inline-block;
  }
 #right {
   height: 100%;
   width: 20%;
      display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   float: right;
   
 }
 #name {
      font-family: big john;
      font-size: 50px;
   width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
      border-bottom: 1px solid;   
   color: white;
 }
 .wot {
   background-color: #E6C88C;
 }
</style>
<head><title>Film Club</title></head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="header">
  <h1 id="name">The Film Club</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="left", class="wot">
        <p>Test</p>
  </div>
  <div id="right", class="wot">
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This answer could use some explanation.